# Identify tongue in cheek movie with exploding heart punch/technique

Tags: identify-this-movie

I've been trying to find a movie for years on and off. The problem is searching - the keywords return too many potential movies, so am hoping this will jog someone's memory, even though that is a long shot.

---

### Era/Genre

I watched it between 10 or maybe 20 years ago - am 80% sure.

At the time it seemed like an older movie, like it was from the 70's or possibly early 80s  - am only 60% sure, could have been any date given I watched it a long time ago.

I recall it was martial arts related (even if only loosely), and the protagonist was trained.
But it was not a serious martial arts movie, it was slightly tongue in cheek - I think intentionally, rather than how some people perceive *old* martial arts movies to be silly/funny.

The humour, if I remember correctly, is *similar* to "Kung Pow" (but it is not that) but a bit more toned down - i.e. not quite as silly, but this could possibly be there were less jokes.

### Country of Origin/Language

I think it's an American movie, based on what I recall from the protagonist - 75% sure (ish).

It was also English spoken language - 98% sure (do not remember subs at all).

---

### Main identifying part

The main thing I remember is the protagonist was wandering like a nomad across vast open lands, not desert.

He came across a small hut, about 6/8 feet wide (made of wood or could have been hide covered, not sure).

He then for *some reason* hit someone in the chest in a very particular way - like the Kill Bill "Five Point Palm Exploding Heart Technique" (but not that).

The reason for the attack, I think, was the other person was coming to kill him, I *think* a contract out on him, but not 100% sure.

The punch might not have been "5 point", I seem to recall he did something similar, then stood back.

The outcome for the person he hit was death - either heart stopped, exploded, or I *think* the chest exploded out in an over the top manner (was possibly *intentionally* silly/OTT).

I *seem* to recall there was a youngish boy stood close by watching all of this (about 10-12 years old, possibly lived in the hut), and the protagonist said something to him.
I think it was along the lines of something corny, and then he walked off nonchalantly as if he had said something amazing.

Comment: Now that's actually an ID question with *effort*. Congratulations and welcome to the site!

Comment: That being said, seeing how *Kill Bill* was influenced by pretty much *everything*, there might be a chance its "5 point exploding heart technique" might have been a reference to this movie, if they were sufficiently similar. So looking at that movie's influences and the movies it referenced might be a good starting point.

Comment: @TomCody Thanks :) Been deliberating over posting this for a while. It's a long shot, but you never know... I'll try that. not exaggerating I've probs spent 50+ hours searching this over the years on and off. Trawled through all sorts of movies, stars names, etc.

Comment: @James Is it in English? Is it likely an American film?

Comment: @Catija I've squeezed my brain and get the impression it's American. I've updated the post for language/origin

Comment: Reminds me of the [Kung Fu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_(TV_series)) series. Though it doesn't sound like it's what you're looking for.

Comment: It's been a while, but when I hear tongue-in-cheek martial arts movies, I think of [They Call Me Bruce](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084786/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) and the sequel [They Still Call Me Bruce](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094131/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2). Could those be what you're looking for?

Comment: @TimS. No, it's not those, but a *huge* thanks for introducing me to them! I've just seen a few clips and am going to watch them with the kids and will certainly have a good laugh! :D Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, based on your description, I think the movie you are talking is 
"Fist of the North Star"

Here is the imdb voice

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113074/

The Live action movie was made in the 1995 (exactly 20 years ago).

The story is poorly adapted from the anime "Hokuto no Ken"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fist_of_the_North_Star

a post-apocaliptic wasteland is the main scenario of this anime, an epic story of love, fights and mutants...

Comment: YES! years of searching the internet for mountains of keywords is finally over! Thank you so much!! Although, re-reading my question description I obviously have a terrible memory. I remember the punch scene at 0:54 differently with heart exploding, but it being a head explode is obviously why I could only find Kill Bill in my searching , and it wasn't tongue in cheek at all. But this is it. Honestly, I have just sighed a bit of relief.

Comment: Did you just sign up to post this?

Comment: well you were young, and this movie is tongue in cheek after all, due to bad acting and poor visual style... 

I was 15 when I see for the first time the anime "Hokuto no Ken"... 
Now I am 43... (gosh... seems yesterday) :D

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3WCNwuuX1w

Comment: Not far behind you, and yes, people lie at my birthday, I'm still 20 AFAIK...:D